# Отфильтровать 2D массив по элементам N-го столбца

Tags: python, numpy

Из файла загружается массив в виде: `[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]..]`.

Kак его отфильтровать, например, по третьему элементу каждого внутреннего массива?

Comment: "отфильтровать" - можно понимать по-разному. Что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Нужно убрать не подходящие внутренние массивы

Comment: приведите пример входных и выходных данных в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [199]: a = np.arange(40).reshape(-1, 4)

In [200]: a
Out[200]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30, 31],
       [32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39]])
```

оставляем только те строки, в которых элементы третьего столбца (с индексом `2`) делятся на `3` без остатка:

```
In [201]: a[a[:, 2] % 3 == 0]
Out[201]:
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [28, 29, 30, 31]])
```